# Toolbar in Search Results is dissapearing in HTML output

Tags: html, jquery, toolbar, madcap

I am using MadCap Flare software to create HTML output of my template document.
I am using some JQuery code to be inserted in the output HTML.
The code is here:

```
<Script>$('<link>').appendTo($('head')).attr({
    type: 'text/css', 
    rel: 'stylesheet',
    href: 'Content/Resources/Stylesheets/Tripane.css'
});</Script>
```

Unfortunately, after including this script in the output, the HTML somehow looses the default Toolbar in the Results pane of my HTML site.
[image]
Normally it should look like this:
[image]
and the code in **Inspector** tab should be like this.
[image]
However, this line is missing in my output!

In the **Console** tab I am not receiving anything special.

Do You have any idea why the toolbar is missing? Where am I supposed to search for this bug.

Comment: Have the elements in question actually disappeared from the DOM, or are they maybe just hidden by newly applied CSS now?

Comment: In my opinion they rather dissapeared from DOM as the CSS applied contained no `class="buttons toolbar-buttons popup-container"` which dissappeared in a browser

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
$('<link>')
.appendTo($('head'))
.attr({type:'text/css',rel:'stylesheet'})
.attr('href', 'Content/Resources/Stylesheets/Tripane.css');
```

Comment: No, unfortunately it does not. 
Why this change in `attr` method could work in your opinion?